# Wear slippers or put on slippers

Tags: phrases, american-english

Which is the most correct one?

1) My shoes are lost from the shop, kindly allow me to wear slippers today.

2) My shoes are lost from the shop, kindly allow me to put on slippers today.

Comment: yes my bad, but correct the sentence please.

Comment: Losing something *from* a place is not idiomatic. And I kindly suggest you look up the words "put on" and "wear" in various online dictionaries, especially Oxford and Merriam-Webster; this site expects you to do some minimum amount of research before asking a question (that is, we are not Hello Native). Also, this site is really not for such basic questions about English. You could try Stack Exchange: English Language Learners. Have a terrific day and weekend and a terrific new year.

Comment: @green_ideas '[W]e are not Hello Native'? Is this a reference to the typical (/an actual)  basic English Q & A site? It has a vaguely off flavour, and I can't find much on the web. (Otherwise, I'm with you entirely.)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Neither. With minimal redaction, I'd reiterate the sentence to 'I lost my shoes at the shop today. Kindly, allow me to wear slippers today', or 'My shoes have been missing from the shop today. Kindly, allow me to wear slippers today'.

Comment: Repetition of 'today' seems unnecessary, especially since it isn't clear from the original sentences when the shoes were lost.

Comment: It's an assumption. It could be yesterday, or even yesteryear. If you have a better explanation on the original question, feel free to pipe in.

Comment: The insertion of a comma after 'Kindly' seems very antiquated. // Please check questions for suitability for ELU (aimed at linguists and proficient users) before giving an 'answer', or other unsuitable questions will be encouraged.

Comment: Just because it might seem antiquated, it doesn't necessarily mean that it's erroneous. Commas are meant to eliminate obfuscation. Please understand before 'commenting' if anyone really needs someone to point out irrelevant and trivial elements to an answer. I don't understand how an archaic grammatical element is related with how unsuitable the questions are.

Comment: I can't see anything here addressing the OP's actual question (about any difference between ***wear** slippers* and ***put on** slippers*). All we have is the recommendation to include ***kindly*** (a somewhat starchily formal alternative to standard ***please***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I suppose the answer’s opening “Neither” sidesteps that neatly, but no reason is given for why either doesn’t work.

Comment: @lawrence, please first read on tenses and then attempt to refute something. Can you give me a single reason why either is grammatically right, considering you maintain proper semantics?

Comment: @Noaman It is up to each answer to prove its point. I don’t think there’s a problem with the grammar of the originals if you replaced the commas with semicolons.

Comment: You might also have a typo in your answer: you use the term “reiterate”, but the answer doesn’t reiterate anything in the question.

Comment: @lawrence, show me where you've proved your point. And pray, tell me, if you are literate enough, how 'are' can be used to denote past tense?

Comment: As I said earlier, it is up to each answer to prove its point. That is a Stack Exchange policy and is an important part of the community’s attempt to build a high-quality repository of questions and answers. You have merely stated stated your point but haven’t proven it. Hence the onus is on you to show that you are correct. Some ways that ELU.SE recognises are logical reasoning, showing established usage of the form asserted, or even appealing to authority where appropriate. Personal experience is fine in some cases, but it leaves one exposed to the ‘not in *my* experience’ reply.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to add support for your position. Again, that’s Stack Exchange policy. Comments can be deleted at a whim by (diamond) moderators, so the only place to record changes more permanently is in the post itself. The edit-history will show most of the changes.